# How to get the list of files of specific extension in bash in just one line?

Tags: bash, extglob

This is how I can get `*.png` files from the `positive` folder sub-directories:

```
FILES=./positive/*/*.png
```

How to modify this command to get both `*.png`, `*.jpg` and `*.bmp` files? Just one line.

Comment: Solutions do not belong in questions. Use the checkbox by a solution to accept it, or you can "Add an Answer" to add your own solution to the answers area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just use `find`:

```
find ./positive/ -name *.png
```

In order to use it for `*.png*`, `*.jpg` and `*.bmp`, you may take advantage of `-o` option which stands for "or" keyword. With it, you can join a few `-name <NAME>` expressions:

```
find ./positive/ -name *.png -o -name *.jpg -o -name *.bmp
```

or alternatively (if you are keen on graphical `or` operator):

```
find ./positive/ -name *.png || -name *.jpg || -name *.bmp
```

Furthermore, if you are not certain that all of the files have lowercase names - you may need to use `-iname` (case insensitive) option instead of `-name`.

Comment: Nice one! So to add them to array I should simply: `FILES=($(find ./positive/ -name *.png -o -name *.jpg -o -name *.bmp))`

Comment: @HappyTorturer Sure, however if you want your `FILES` variable to keep all the files, I'd rather skip one subshell parenthesis and leave the expression like this: `FILES=$(find ./positive/ -name *.png -o -name *.jpg -o -name *.bmp)` (notice there is no embrasing parenthesis around `$`)

Comment: yes, thank you for that note. But, however, there is a slight difference here: in case of skipping that parenthesis, you will not be able to get the `FILES` array element manually by index. E.g.: `echo ${FILES[2]}` will return nothing. In `for` and `for each` loops it works though.

Comment: This solution doesn't work

Answer (score 3):

```
shopt -s extglob                     # enable extended globbing
ls ./positive/*/*.@(png|jpg|bmp)
```

> `?(pattern-list)`:   Matches zero or one occurrence of the given patterns
>
> `*(pattern-list)`:   Matches zero or more occurrences of the given patterns
>
> `+(pattern-list)`:   Matches one or more occurrences of the given patterns
>
> `@(pattern-list)`:   Matches one of the given patterns
>
> `!(pattern-list)`:   Matches anything except one of the given patterns

Source: http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/bash-extended-globbing

---

To fill an array:

```
shopt -s extglob
files=( ./positive/*/*.@(png|jpg|bmp) )
for f in "${files[@]}"; do echo "$f"; done
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! There's something bad about `ls` command though: `ls` is unable to interpret files with spaces correctly. Consider the following example: `touch 'he ll o.txt' ; FILES=$(ls); for f in ${FILES[@]}; do echo $f; done`. You will notice 'he ll o .txt' splitted into three pieces : he, ll and o.txt.

Comment: This solution works for me, should have been accepted answer.