# Move all files except some files

Tags: linux, bash, centos

I have a folder containing thousands of log files for months ago with the following schema:

`log_date_view.txt or log_date_click.txt`

I need to move all the files to other folder except log files for March and April which have the following naming convention,

`201604* and 201603*`

How can I do this in bash?

Comment: See e.g. http://superuser.com/questions/210168/bash-moving-files-except-files-with-a-given-suffix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With GNU bash 4:

```
shopt -s extglob
echo mv !(log_20160[34]*.txt) other_folder
```

If everything looks okay remove `echo`.

---

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32309080/3776858